# Vue warn Avoid mutating a prop "taskToEdit"

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

i have a problem with my props editToTask :

*app.js:42491 [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "taskToEdit"*

component TaskComponent.vue

```
<template>
...
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-secondary"
          data-toggle="modal"
          data-target="#editModal"
          @click="getTask(task.id)"
        >Editer</button>
      </li>
      <edit-task v-bind:taskToEdit="taskToEdit"></edit-task>
...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      tasks: {},
      taskToEdit: "",
    };
  },

  methods: {

    getTask(id) {
      axios
        .get("http://localhost:3000/tasks/edit/" + id)
        .then((res) => (this.taskToEdit = res.name))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    },
};
</script>
```

component EditTaskComponent :

```
<template>
...
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for>Nom des tâches</label>
                <textarea name="name" id="name" rows="4" class="form-control" v-model="taskToEdit"></textarea>
              </div>
            </form>
...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["taskToEdit"],
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be solved easier, you should not change props. `v-model` solves this pretty well you should look into [component v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components).

Firstly you can make your child component work with v-model, use a prop named value instead in the child component. Which represent the task value.

```
<script>
export default {
  props: ["value"],
};
</script>
```

Secondly avoid using v-model to mutate the prop. Instead emit an input event.

```
<textarea name="name" id="name" rows="4" class="form-control" :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"></textarea>
```

In your parent component you can use v-model like this now.

```
<edit-task v-model="taskToEdit"></edit-task>
```

Comment: Thx, but are you sure for `@input="$emit('input', $event)`, because i cant write in textearea `[object InputEvent]`

Comment: Just tested the code instead of $event it should have been $event.target.value edited the answer too

Comment: Work ! Thx a lot !